# DD Roundies not working in IE when element has gradient filter

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

I'm using DD roundies on a list element (li) that also has a filter applied for gradient and the rounded corners dont appear, but if I remove the gradient the rounded corners appear. Is there something I can do to fix this or is this a known limitation with roundies?

```
#hero-tabs li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:279px;
    /*height:100px;*/
    font-size:11px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color:#fff;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#555;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#222222, endColorstr=#666666);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#222222', endColorstr='#666666')";
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#666), to(#222));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #666, #222);
}
```

---

```
DD_roundies.addRule('#hero-tabs .first-tab', '0 0 0 5px');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have ound this also and there appears to be no work around at present. You can have one or the other, not both.

IE applies the gradient filter to the original element so the rounded elements from dd_roundies don't cover it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a limitation with roundies, it's a limitation with `filter` gradients. This is proved by the fact that `filter` gradients also cause similar problems in IE9 with standard `border-radius` corners.

There is no easy work-around available; the best solution is simply not to use those `filter` gradients in older versions of IE; so IE8 and earlier would just a fall-back solid colour background.

IE9 does have a work-around, as it can use an SVG image with a gradient as the background embedded in the CSS as a data-URL. It's a bit clunky, but it does work. IE8 doesn't have this option though.

If you must use gradients in IE8, you're pretty much forced to stick with the `filter` styles, and live with the bugs.

There is one other option though -- [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). This is a small JS library similar to DD_Roundies in that it adds `border-radius` support to old IE versions. But in addition, it also does gradients. My advice, therefore would be to use CSS3Pie instead of DD_Roundies, and it will deal with both issues for you at once.

Hope that helps.